# Yii 2 как правильно создать правила для urlManager'a

Tags: php, yii2

Не могу не как разобраться, проблема с yii - есть адрес страницы которая генерируется используя передаваемый ID в гет параметре.

```
site/decoritem?id=30
```

Я хочу так же передавать не только параметр id но и title но что бы в строке запросы был title:

```
site/decoritem/title
```

Подскажите как это реализуется, потому что добавив правило в urlManager не чего не срабатывает

```
'urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'rules' => [
                'decortem/<title:\d+>'=> 'decoritem<id:\d+>',
            ],
```

Ссылку на эти страницы генерирую при помощи

```
 \yii\helpers\Url::to(['/decoritem/', 'id' => $model->id])
```

подскажите как правильно реализовать? файл .htaccess поправил по инструкциям в интернетах

Comment: "\d - Цифровой символ", а title - строка из символов любых, разве нет?

Comment: а да, я просто пока тестирую, передаю туда id, у меня и так не срабатывает именно что бы был ЧПУ адрес

Comment: просто не ясно что в итоге должно быть, вот передали строку - должен отработать тот же метод, в который передаётся id тоже? а что в методе будет тогда происходить?........ плюс если использовать типизацию - такое не прокатит, потому что если написать `actionTest(int $id)`, то он просто будет ругаться на строку в итоге

Comment: В методе прописано использование get параметра id. Он будет отрабатывать согласно переданным данным. Вне зависимости от того что мы передадим в title. Меня интересует как отобразить title в url, но не отображать id. Что бы я мог сделать название категории а не id категории.

Comment: допустим мы вообще уберем тип из правила `'decortem/<title>'=> 'decoritem<id>',` уже попробовал по разному, не могу понять почему не срабатывает. Страница грузится, но всё равно в адресе строки "decoritem?id=30&title=categoryTittle1"